# Formula for Calculated Value

Tags: document-library, calculated-column-formula

I have two columns (for example column A and column B) with the type of information as choice. When i select value in column A then column B should show values related to column A only. Other values from column B should not be visible.
How can I create rule for this?

Answer (score 1):

That type of functionality can't be achieved with calculated columns. You are going to have to use JavaScript/jQuery on the editform.aspx page of your document library to get that. Fortunately there is a library called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) that has a function specifically for cascading choice fields.

[Cascading dropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Hope following article will guide you to achieve the functionality you want to implement.

http://www.uccorner.com/54/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down/comment-page-1/

Comment: Hi Anuja! Please add the details from the link to you answer. If the link breaks, your answer will be of no help as it is written now.